# css @media хак только для Android

Tags: android, css, media-queries

Использую

```
@media 'all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm)'
```

для Chromium, но нужно отдельно написать блок стиля для Андроид.

Пробовал (c browserhacks.com) `screen and (min-width:0\0)` и `screen and (min-width:0\-)` - не работает.

есть ли медиа-хак только для Андроида?

Comment: @SilencedOne05
Спасибо! чуть много дополнительного кода в моем случае, но если ничего лучше не найду - думаю, буду использовать. Можете это как ответ здесь поставить на такой случай...

Comment: Поставил, как ответ

Comment: Рекомендую вам определять не браузер, а поддержку необходимых фич. В чем ваша конкретная задача?

Comment: @SilencedOne05
Кросбаузерная верстка. Например, на мобильных шрифт courier не отображается, элементы :before, отступы разные на разных браузерах...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, cssuseragent.org - то, что вам нужно.

Comment: вот, нашлось что-то хорошое: к той медиа для хромиума добавляю and (pointer: coarse) - вроде, работает на Андроиде только. https://css-tricks.com/touch-devices-not-judged-size/

Comment: @CodeGust, что же. Хорошо. Думаю, вопрос можно закрывать, верно?

Comment: да, спасиБо за помощь!